# Converting the date given from Apple receipts to a .net DateTime object

Tags: c#, .net, in-app-purchase

Although it's probably something simple - I couldn't find any place that gives any (correct) solution for it...

Apple receipts return dates in RFC 3339
It looks like that:

> 2016-08-10 19:47:16 America/Los_Angeles
>
> 2016-08-11 02:42:16 Etc/GMT

Any solution I found does not handle the timezone correctly...
for example:
DateTime object doesn' seem to have a string converter for this format at all.

Another solution I found:

```
string tTranDatStr = "2016-08-11 02:42:16 Etc/GMT";
trans_date = XmlConvert.ToDateTime(tTranDatStr, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Local);
```

But it throws:

> The string '2016-08-11 02:42:16 Etc/GMT' is not a valid AllXsd value.

Is there any elegant solution that is also correct (converts the time to the current locale timezone...)?

THANKS!!

Comment: That's not RFC 3339, which only deals with UTC offsets, not time zone identifiers. Does it always use Etc/GMT? If so, you could just strip that and use `DateTime.ParseExact`, specifying that it's already in UTC.

Comment: Apple claims it is RFC 3339 - and I cannot really argue with them... 
I've also seen that: 2016-08-10 19:47:16 America/Los_Angeles
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html

Comment: Well I looked at RFC 3339 this morning and didn't see anything about time zone IDs... Will look again later, but I suspect they mean that the bit before the ID is RFC 3339. You could use Noda Time for this - can't post an answer now, but will try later.

Comment: So I read the standard as well, they do have "time zones" as offsets, but not in this format. Apple also does not have a "T" between the date and the time.. which means - they don't hold the standard at all.. yet.. this is what I get from apple, and I still need/want a way to translate the receipt to an accurate time (while considering the time and the offests of the time zone correctly...)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET has no built-in support for the zoneinfo/Olson/tz/IANA time zones (whatever you want to call them...) that are being used here. Fortunately, my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project does.

Here's some code using Noda Time 1.3.2 which successfully parses both the sample values you've given. The natural type for the data you've presented is `ZonedDateTime`, which is a date and time in a known time zone. Next, you could convert it to an `OffsetDateTime`, which is a bit like .NET's `DateTimeOffset` (which you can convert it to).

Personally I'd recommend trying to use the Noda Time types throughout your code - the aim of the project is to make date/time code a lot less fiddly and error-prone. If you really need to convert to the BCL types though, you can certainly do so.

```
using System;
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Text;

class Program
{
    private static readonly ZonedDateTimePattern ApplePattern =
        ZonedDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z", DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ParseApple("2016-08-10 19:47:16 America/Los_Angeles");
        ParseApple("2016-08-11 02:42:16 Etc/GMT");
    }

    static void ParseApple(string text)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Parsing {text}");
        ParseResult<ZonedDateTime> result = ApplePattern.Parse(text);
        if (!result.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Parse failed! {result.Exception.Message}");
            return;
        }
        ZonedDateTime zonedValue = result.Value;
        Console.WriteLine($"ZonedDateTime: {zonedValue}");
        // OffsetDateTime is a Noda Time type...
        OffsetDateTime offsetValue = zonedValue.ToOffsetDateTime();
        Console.WriteLine($"OffsetDateTime: {offsetValue}");
        // DateTimeOffset is the BCL type...
        DateTimeOffset dto = offsetValue.ToDateTimeOffset();
        Console.WriteLine($"DateTimeOffset: {dto}");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Parsing 2016-08-10 19:47:16 America/Los_Angeles
ZonedDateTime: 2016-08-10T19:47:16 America/Los_Angeles (-07)
OffsetDateTime: 2016-08-10T19:47:16-07
DateTimeOffset: 10/08/2016 19:47:16 -07:00

Parsing 2016-08-11 02:42:16 Etc/GMT
ZonedDateTime: 2016-08-11T02:42:16 Etc/GMT (+00)
OffsetDateTime: 2016-08-11T02:42:16Z
DateTimeOffset: 11/08/2016 02:42:16 +00:00
```

Comment: I started using it - seems like it's working for me (I trust once it doesn't give an exception it works correctly...)

All I do with this data is store it in .net, but I read it from Apple devices... (or when users report issues - then it's my log..)

I am shocked Apple do not follow the standard they claim they do...
I reported it as a bug to apple, though I do not think they'll do anything ...